# C# Attributes that figures out if another attribute is applied

Tags: c#, attributes

I am working on a Asp.net MVC project and I am wondering if there is a way for the attributes to talk to other attributes.

For example, I have the following attributes

```
public class SuperLoggerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //Do something super
    }
}

public class NormalLoggerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //Do something normal ONLY if the super attribute isn't applied 
    }
}
```

And I have the following controllers

```
[NormalLogger]
public class NormalBaseController : Controller
{

}

public class PersonController: NormalBaseController
{

}

[SuperLogger]
public class SuperController: NormalBaseControler
{

}
```

So basically, I want my SuperController to use SuperLogger and ignore NormalLogger (which was applied in the base), and PersonController should use the NormalLogger since it's not "overrided" by the SuperLogger. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks,

Chi

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have `SuperLoggerAttribute` inherit from `NormalLoggerAttribute` and override the `Log` method?

Comment: -1: By doing this, SuperController would have both the NormalLoggerAttribute and the SuperLoggerAttribute applied, which is not what Chi Chan intended to do.

Comment: Does SuperController not already have both, by virtue of extending an attributed base class?

Comment: Thank you arootbeer. But by doing so I will have to Add [NormalLogger] on PersonController. I want to avoid doing that because I have a lot of controllers that inherit from the base and I only have one "Super" controller that I want a different behavior with.

Comment: Why would you have to add NormalLogger on PersonController?  It would still inherit the NormalLogger attribute from NormalController as it's doing now.

Comment: I have just tried this. If you keep [NormalLogger] on BaseController, SuperController will execute NormalLogger (defined in BaseController), and then it will execute SuperLogger (defined in SuperController). I can inherit SuperLogger from NormalLogger to save code, but it won't stop it from executing NormalLogger.

Comment: Okay.  It sounds like the runtime is calling OnActionExecuted explicitly on both attributes, then.  At this point it appears we diverge into synchronization code, which I'd think is a Really Bad Idea because the NormalLogger is not going to be the same instance as the SuperLogger.  Looks like you're off to flow control similar to Tom's suggestion.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure how flow control can help out with this. If I apply [Logger(LoggerType.Normal)] on BaseController and [Logger(LoggerType.Super)] on SuperController. It will still call [Logger(LoggerType.Normal)] on SuperController because SuperController is inherited from BaseController. I am currently using a "God object" to hack away with this. But we all know it's a bad idea to play God. ;)

Comment: "If you do it right, no one will be sure you've done anything at all."

Comment: Now that that's out of the way - The only way I can see is to check whether the class to which the attribute is applied is SuperController, and if it is then don't run the code in NormalLogger.  I have very little experience with attributing, so I can't even tell you for sure that you can check the class to which an attribute is applied.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
public enum LoggerTypes
{
    Normal,
    Super
}

public class LoggerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public LoggerAttribute() : base()
    {
        LoggerType = LoggerTypes.Normal;
    }

    public LoggerAttribute(LoggerTypes loggerType) : base()
    {
        LoggerType = loggerType;
    }

    public LoggerTypes LoggerType
    {
        get; 
        set;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (LoggerType == LoggerTypes.Super)
        {
            //
        }
        else
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
[Logger(LoggerTypes.Normal)]
```

or

```
[Logger(LoggerTypes.Super)]
```